# PHP Regex to extract columns of text delimited by multiple spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a chunk of text extracted from a tabular layout that resembles this:

```
Waiting Period                             30 days of employment                 30 days of employment                    30 days of employment
 Benefit amount                                   Flat $150,000                        Flat $100,000                              Flat $60,000
 Maximum benefit                                    $150,000                              $100,000                                  $60,000
 Contributions                                  Noncontributory                       Noncontributory                           Noncontributory
   Participation requirement                         100.00%                               100.00%                                  100.00%
---
Benefit amount                                            Flat $40,000                                                  Flat $20,000
 Maximum benefit                                             $40,000                                                       $20,000
 Compulsory coverage                                            Yes                                                           Yes
 Contributions                                           Noncontributory                                               Noncontributory
Waiting Period                                        30 days of employment                                      30 days of employment
```

Phrases like `Waiting Period`, or `Contributions` are labels for the row.  A variable number of columns then follow, separated by a variable number of whitespaces.

I am struggling to land on a regular expression that can target a particular row based on the label, and then extract the content of those variable number of columns.  I think I have constructed the label identifier and the capture groups to identify the columns.  But the expression seems to stop at the first match.

```
(?:\s*Waiting Period)(?:(?:\s{2,})(.*?)(?:\s{2,}|\n|$))
```

The above expression in preg_match_all:

```
preg_match_all("/(?:\s*Waiting Period)(?:(?:\s{2,})(.*?)(?:\s{2,}|\n))/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

produces:

```
array(2) {
0   =>  array(2){
                    0   =>  Waiting Period                             30 days of employment
                    1   =>  
                            Waiting Period                                        30 days of employment 
                }
1   =>  array(2){
                    0   =>  30 days of employment
                    1   =>  30 days of employment   
                }
}
```

As you can see, the match correctly identifies the target rows based on the label, extracts the first column and quits.  I don't know how to instruct the process to keep going until each matched row is processed until the end of line.

My question is:  is my regex approach salvageable to accomplish my objective?  Or, have I misunderstood preg_match_all and will only ever get one instance of the capture subgroup?

Comment: So, two or more spaces delimit the column?

Comment: Basically, PCRE engine's can't capture a variable number of groups (columns in your case). So you would have to capture the columns row, then parse that separately. Probably in a while find/find-next loop, you'd use `/^Waiting Period\h+(.*)/mg`, then split $1 on `/\s{2,}/` to get the columns.

Comment: @sln:  yes, 2+ spaces delimit the columns.  I was afraid that the "variable number of groups" was not possible.  I was hoping that I just misunderstood the limitation and that my regex was just incorrect.  As a longshot:  are you aware of whether constructs like preg_match_all would give me that global search?

Comment: I think preg_match_all is going to blindly put into an array the capture groups for each instance of the match. So, still the same, won't get variable number of capture groups. Only Dot-Net does that in their `CaptureCollection` class.

Answer (score 1):

This is because  `(?:\s{2,}|\n)` two or more spaces or newline character. So your regex stops until it finds another set of continuous space characters.

```
^\s*Waiting Period\s{2,}(.*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rE9iJ0/2)

Comment: Avinash, thank you for a quick, concise and correct answer!  For my own clarification:  I don't need to try and match the spacing *after* the chunk I'm trying to capture because I'm already matching the the whitespace in front of that target.  Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, need some additional clarification.  It appears that your corrected version does match through to the end of the line.  However, all content after the row label is matched into a single group.  I am looking to match each chunk of text into a separate group.  Is this possible?  

BTW, I do understand that I could split the matched string in a separate step, but I am attempting to avoid that extra step and extract the matches into distinct groups directly.  Thanks!

Comment: @ShaheebRoshan I need some clarification regarding the project you sent to me. When you come online?